# CSS: To objects floating left, without overlapping

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a navbar and I want to have the buttons in that same navbar, float to the left inside the navbar div that only covers 75% of the width of the page and is in the middle.

What I have in terms of HTML/CSS:

```
<div id="header">
            <div id="navbar">
                <div id="navbar-left">
                    <div id="navbar-button1" class="navbar-button">
                        <div class="navbar-button-text">Page1</div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="navbar-button2" class="navbar-button">
                        <div class="navbar-button-text">Page2</div>
                            <div class="navbar-dropdown">
                                <div class="navbar-dropdown-button">Page2</div>
                                <div class="navbar-dropdown-button">SPage2</div>
                                <div class="navbar-dropdown-button">SPage3</div>
                                <div class="navbar-dropdown-button">SPage4</div>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="navbar-button3" class="navbar-button">
                        <div class="navbar-button-text">Page3</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="navbar-right"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

body {
    background-color: #E5E5E5;
    margin: 0em;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#main {
    background-color: #E3E3E3;
    width: 75%;
    margin: auto;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 12.5%;
}

#header{
    background-color: #66CDAA;
    height: 3em;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 998;
}

#navbar{
    background-color: #66CDAA;
    height: 3em;
    width: 75%;
    top: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
}

.right{
    border-left: 0.1em solid #E5E5E5;
    height: 100%;
    width: 25%;
    float: right;
    z-index: 3;
}

#footer{
    height: 5em;
    clear: both;
    z-index: 3;
}

.navbar-button{
    height: 3em;
    line-height: 3em;
    width: 25%;
    z-index: 1;
    position: fixed;
}

.navbar-button-text{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    font-family: 'bebas_neueregular';
    color: #E3E3E3;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.navbar-dropdown-button{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    font-family: 'bebas_neueregular';
    color: #E5E5E5;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.navbar-dropdown{
    position: absolute;
    top:0%;
    width:100%;
    background-color: #57a58a;
    opacity: 0;
}

#navbar-button1{
    left: 12.5%;
    float: left;
}
#navbar-button1:hover{
    background-color: #57a58a;
}

#navbar-button2{
    left: 37.5%;
}

#navbar-button2:hover .navbar-dropdown{
    opacity: 1;
}

#navbar-button3{
    left: 62.5%;

}

#navbar-button3:hover{
    background-color: #57a58a;
}
```

Explaining that:

- I have a DIV(main) that covers 75% of width and 100% of the height of
  the page.
- I have a DIV(header) inside a DIV(main) that covers the same width but only 3em of the height of the page.
- I two DIVs(navbar-left and navbar-right) that have no sizes as of now.
- I have three DIVs(navbar-button1, navbar-button2 and navbar-button3) inside a DIV(navbar-left) that each have 1/4 of the page's width.

What I want:

- I want the three DIVs (navbar-button1, navbar-button2 and navbar-button3) floating to the left inside of the DIV(navbar-left).

The two problems that occur when doing that:

- Instead of floating inside the div, they floated all the way to the left of the page.
- Instead of floating one next to the other, they floated on top of another.

Could you help me with that?

Thanks

Comment: I pasted these inside of a jsfiddle and it looked fine.

Comment: They look fine because I've set the position I wanted them to be; they're not floating on the page, and once I make them float to the left, they all float to the left and stack on top of each other.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see right now, in your CSS you have:

```
#navbar-button1 {
    left: 12.5%;
    float: left;
}

#navbar-button2 {
    left: 37.5%;
} 

#navbar-button3 {
    left: 62.5%;
}
```

This will float navbar-button1 left, but the other two aren't floating. 
Make each have the `float: left;` property through the `navbar-button` class. This will make them stand side-by-side as you want.

```
#header{
    background-color: #66CDAA;
    height: 3em;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 998;
}

#navbar{
    background-color: #66CDAA;
    height: 3em;
    width: 75%;
    top: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

The buttons seem to be on the left of the whole page because you're not centering or moving your navbar div at all. They're actually floating inside the div but the header and navbar divs are resting in the same place.

Comment: If I float all three to the left of the page, they go completely to the left of the page(and not the DIV), stacking on top of each other, instead of being next to each other.

The header and the navbar should be fixed in that place. They are like dividing the page, and that division shouldn't move. I want other DIVs to float inside that non-moving DIV.
If I do what you suggested (with the floating), this happens: http://jsbin.com/gajovageze

Comment: Actually, sorry for my quick post here; but I just pasted your code into a file and it works just fine! I'm not sure where you're getting the error... http://pastebin.com/LMEQAFAQ
Here's a screenshot: https://minus.com/i/QL2DT9xcfo7l

Is that the layout you wanted?

Comment: It works fine with my code, but stops working once I change what you suggested. In the URL you sent me the three buttons weren't floating either, they just had the percentages they should be from the left.

Comment: I'm at a loss, I ran the same code as you did and it works exactly like you wanted it :/ interesting.

Comment: Could you send me the code? As I said before, when I run my code it works, but with their set positions and not floating. That is the problem.